# Eclipse console window that respects cursor position calls allowing a progress bar

Tags: java, eclipse, console, terminal, progress-bar

I'm using the code from [this website](http://nakkaya.com/2009/11/08/command-line-progress-bar/) (Nurullah Akkaya):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        printProgBar(i);
    }
}

public static void printProgBar(int percent){
    StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder("[");

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        if( i < (percent/2)){
            bar.append("=");
        }else if( i == (percent/2)){
            bar.append(">");
        }else{
            bar.append(" ");
        }
    }

    bar.append("]   " + percent + "%     ");
    System.out.print("\r" + bar.toString());
}
```

For whatever reason this is outputted line for line like so:

```
[>                                                 ]   0%     
[=====>                                            ]   10%     
[==========>                                       ]   20%     
[===============>                                  ]   30%     
[====================>                             ]   40%     
[=========================>                        ]   50%     
[==============================>                   ]   60%     
[===================================>              ]   70%     
[========================================>         ]   80%     
[=============================================>    ]   90%
```

When really I want it to be updating a single line, as per a normal console window.

Is there anyway to emulate this behaviour so it works in an Eclipse window?

Comment: unlikely; unless you output the delete character the size of that bar. I believe it is character ASCII code 0x7f according to wikipedia

Comment: Are you calling this function in loop ? If so, please show that code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sources of the Console view of Eclipse, I can see that a pure "CR" is not supported in the emulator. So, the answer is: no, this is not possible.